# deactivate growlmail rss notification

Tags: mail.app, notifications, growl, rss

Is it possible to tell growlmail to stop notifying me on RSS feeds and just show me the new mails I get?

It is getting really disturbing when I get some 30 or more RSS Notifiers when I'm working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just notifications on the new mails you have in your *Inbox(es)*, then there is a setting for that in GrowlMail configuration tab. Not in Growl System Preferences, but in Mail.app Growl Mail preferences.

Comment: Thanx! Didn't know that in the mail.app there was a growl tab where I could configure the notifications